# How do I install pip with Python 3.8.0a3 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: python

```
$ sudo apt install python3.8
[...]
python3.8 is already the newest version (3.8.0~a3-2).

$ sudo apt install python3.8-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-pip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-pip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-pip'

$ python3.8 -m pip
/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip
```

Comment: It is not duplicated, it is specifying python 3.8, not python 3. When installing python 3.8 and exists older versions there is a problem installing pip.

Comment: Can you please edit this question to describe the problem more clearly?

Comment: @Zanna Whats unclear about this question?

Comment: @user48956 my comment is in reply to a flag from the OP which explained why their question is not a duplicate (was being voted to close as such) by describing the problem more clearly. I hoped they would improve the question by adding that information to it. I am slightly uncomfortable editing *myself* to add information from a relatively private channel.

Comment: @Zanna when I installed Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 19.04, it seems like it didn't install pip.